# Firebaselistadapter error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

After updating my application to use the new Firebase, I started receiving the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class java.util.Dictionary
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zzaC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseListAdapter.java:113)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getItem(FirebaseListAdapter.java:102)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:130)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2842)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1884)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:779)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1679)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2632)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2308)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Z

I could not find the location in my code responsible to that error.

Comment: Can you show the code for how you instantiate the `FirebaseListAdapter`? And preferably also the Java class that you are trying to parse the `DataSnapshot` into.

Comment: Does it work if you use a debug version of your apk?